# Failed to create netty connection of HornetQ: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Tags: java, netty, hornetq

I have few local and remote HornetQ client need to connect to the same HornetQ server. I always saw the "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out" exception thrown by HornetQ for the first 2 minutes period when the system started up. After the 2 minutes later, then the connections would connect.

I checked the connections which got exceptions were all from the local HornetQ clients. It confused me cause local connection should not have any issue compared with the remote connection, unless I configured wrong.

Following are the configurations I used:
[image]
Please point out if I made any mistake

The HornetQ version I used is 2.2.5. As far as I know, the HornetQ allows connect from a netty connector to a netty acceptor (if they are configured with the same host and port). Or I should use the physical IP address for the local connection instead of localhost ? Thanks for your sharing

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the ports required for initiating the clustering are already occupied by other processes of your machine. make sure all the required ports are idle and restart the server.

Comment: please comment it or improve your answer